# No matching unique or primary key for this column list even after putting the primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

so I am just starting to learn SQL and can't get a foreign key to reference a primary key.

Here is the table that does not work

```
CREATE TABLE Classification (
    mvID integer,
    genre varchar (20),
    FOREIGN KEY(mvID) REFERENCES Movie(mvID)
);
```

Here is the table that it is referencing

```
CREATE TABLE Movie (
    mvID integer,
    title varchar(40),  
    rating char (2),
    rel_date date,
    length integer,
    studio varchar(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (mvID)
);
```

Whenever I run it always shows me this message

Error report -

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
>   02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
>   *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
>              gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
>              key constraint in the referenced table.
>
> *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
>              catalog view

Comment: Your code works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7040c3fffac1db47289549a5777ceaf0.

Comment: Have you checked that the PK exists in the user_constraints table?

Comment: Is it the case,where you have created movie table without PK, or may be added later and constraint not created somehow. the script provided by you is working fine.

Comment: It is working fine.
Please refer : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7040c3fffac1db47289549a5777ceaf0

Answer (score 0):

Your DDL script works perfectly in Oracle 12c:
Check to see if you had a typo or if you have created the tables in the wrong order.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Movie (
    mvID integer,
    title varchar(40),  
    rating char (2),
    rel_date date,
    length integer,
    studio varchar(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (mvID)
);
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  
Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE Classification (
    mvID integer,
    genre varchar (20),
    FOREIGN KEY(mvID) REFERENCES Movie(mvID)
);
  2    3    4    5  
Table created.

SQL> drop table Classification;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table Movie;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```